# My function isnt getting defined for some reason?

Tags: python, function

I tried to write a function that returns true if there is an integer in a string. However, the function is apparently not defined. When I try to run the code I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    integer(5)
NameError: name 'integer' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
def integer(s):
z = ''
z = z + i
for i in s:
    if s == int:
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Python in that case :)

In Python white space and indentation are essential. Your function needs to be indented correctly, as so:

```
def integer(s):
    z = ''
    z = z + i
    for i in s:
        if s == int:
            return True
```

Now, your function isn't quite doing what you want it to. The `if s == int:` isn't quite the right syntax.
You'd probably want something more like `if s in "0123456789":` because `s` is a string even if it's between 0-9, and make sure at the end of the function to `return False` if the function never found a digit. As so:

```
def integer(s):
    for i in s:
        if s in "0123456789":
            return True
    return False
```

To make sure you can define a simple function, try just doing a hello world program so that you can make sure your definitions are working right.

Answer (score 1):

just a few tips, so the reason why its not defined is because you must indent with python... This is the equivalent to using {} in other languages like java.

Also you shouldn't use a key word like 'int' for variables, a key word is one that has already been defined by python like 'def'...

Good luck with the best language out there :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I also see various errors but I think you are trying to call the function before it is defined. Try something like this:

```
def integer(s):
    if isinstance(s, int):
        return True
    if isinstance(s, str):
        for i in s:
            if i in "0123456789":
                return True
    return False

print(integer(5)) # True
print(integer("123")) # True
print(integer("a212")) # True
print(integer("aaa")) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume indentation is wrong because of copy-pasting.

1. You are trying to access variable `i` *before* there is any, at: `z = z + i`.
2. There is a possibility that your function won't return anything, since you only cover the case when `s` actually contains an int (`return True`).

Apart from those technical problems, you don't use `z` to anything so two first lines can be removed.

In sum:

```
def integer(s):
    for i in s:
        if s == int:
            return True

    return False # In case there is no integer.
```

This method will work fine, however, you can do better:

```
def has_integer(s):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in s)
```